# browser used in ios webview

Tags: ios, webview

I want to know some answer about iOS webview.

1. Which browser iOS use in their webview?
2. Safari browser installed in iOS & webview browser (if safari) are same or there are difference?
3. Is it possible to use installed safari browser inside webview? because my app working in safari browser but not working at webview. my iOS version 11.2 & iphone 7
4. Suppose in my webview chrome used & I uninstalled chrome browser from phone then will my webview work or not?
   Last question is how can I check my webview browser version

Please help.

Comment: What class are you actually using for your web view? `UIWebView`? `WKWebView`? `SFSafariViewController`?

Comment: @rmaddy In fact I am not iOS developer. Just want to know using any class it is possible answer above question

Comment: It's my understanding that all the browsers are based on `WKWebView` (at least for rendering), this might have changed though. It's open source, so if you're really up for a challenge, you can take a look

Comment: But you said your app is working in Safari but not in your web view. So what web view are you talking about?

Comment: @rmaddy I have a vueJS application which is like speech recolonization engine app & its not working in webview but fine in safari browser. Also it is mysterious that it is not working in chrome browser in iOS

Comment: this is why I am suspecting that in iOS webview using chrome like something

Comment: Answer 1: - Safari on iOS Mac

Answer (score 4):

Answer 1: - Safari on iOS Mac

Answer 2: - Similar i Would Say, You can open the page with specified url or if you set url to https://www.google.com/ then you can go anywhere.

Answer 3: - It already uses Safari

Answer 4: - It will work no worries.

If You want to use Wkwebview follow . Do not forget to connect delegate of web View with UiviewController[image]e

Comment: my app working in safari browser but not working at webview. my iOS version 11.2 & iphone 7. So how its happening. My App being crashed in webview

Comment: This is a private app not available in apple store. App crashing when a speech recognition engine initializes but work fine only in safari browser

Comment: There would be some error it might be displaying can you please tell?

Comment: This is the problem that we have not the source code of the app. We are unable to inspect or remote debug for console error. We developed a similar webview app there are showing 'Promise' related error but no details about error

Comment: Oh man that is hard, By the way have you checked the delegate of webView?

Comment: Can you tell whether it is possible to open regular safari browser in webview? because in regular browser it is working

Comment: You can redirect the app to safari in that case

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/187230/discussion-between-rejoanul-alam-and-mayank-wadhwa).